# Comparison between Vaadin and ZK

Tags: java, comparison, vaadin, zk

Does someone know of a comparison between [ZK](http://www.zkoss.org/) and [Vaadin](http://vaadin.com/home)?

I'm especially interested which of the two is better suited for a dynamic web app (i.e. where the layout and POJOs are defined at runtime and can change at any time).

Most examples look pretty good if you have a standard POJO (with a fixed set of fields). But how do the frameworks fare if the POJO is replaced with a `Map<String, Object>` and I need to build the UI depending on the `Map`'s content?

Comment: With Vaadin all the code is java if you don't need sth really custom. As a result, it will work good with POJO (object oriented). Your requriements may be different but losing object orientation may cause more headaches in the future.

Comment: Customers must be able to add custom fields to objects at any time, so we use base POJOs which have a Map field for everything else. We're aware that there is a trade-off but without this, the application would be useless for customers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You find Vaadin oriented comparison/discussion here: [vaadin.com/forum/-/message_boards/view_message/134071](http://vaadin.com/forum/-/message_boards/view_message/134071) and another one (more ZK oriented) here: [jtechnoprojects.blogspot.com/2011/05/zk-vs-vaadin.html](http://jtechnoprojects.blogspot.com/2011/05/zk-vs-vaadin.html)

Furthermore, regarding on your topic about Map content, I think you should be fine with Vaadin's [Item interface](http://vaadin.com/book/-/page/datamodel.items.html). For example the ["PropertiesItem" addon](http://vaadin.com/directory#addon/propertiesitem) is essentially backed by a Map ([java.util.Properties](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) to be exact) and it binds directly to Vaadin [Forms](http://vaadin.com/book/-/page/components.form.html).

Comment: Vaadin got [some performance issue](https://vaadin.com/old-forum/-/message_boards/view_message/3875658). As Sara suggested, remember to implement your own bean container for serving a lot of users.

Answer (score 8):

Both frameworks handle dynamic UI:s just fine. When choosing the framework, you should compare  things like components included, number and quality of add-on components, licensing, documentation, community and so forth.

Comment: +1 for the valuable input; I just can't accept the solution because it doesn't answer the main point (comparison between the two).

Answer (score 3):

As a disclaimer I work for ZK.

There are a lot of features that will help you do what you want to do. You can have a look at the [the product page](http://www.zkoss.org/product/zk) which highlights a lot of features. However, I have highlighted 2 features below which may be of particular use.

### Responsive Design - Changing the layout

This approach was published in ZK 6.5 and enables developers to write applications which change with the layout. This would be very useful to you. It also includes components which change their behaviour depending on whether they are on a Desktop browser, tablet or smartphone.

Information is available [here](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/Small_Talks/2012/September/New_Features_of_ZK_6.5).

### Databinding - Layout & Responding to changes in POJOs

The databinding is based upon MVVM concepts and can respond to changes in your POJOs. You can have different templates which support different POJO states and such like. A good introductory tutorial for our databinding is [this one](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Getting_Started/Get_ZK_Up_and_Running_with_MVVM).